# Transform array of objects into an object

Tags: jquery

I want to iterate an array of objects to create one object, the properties of which are named for the current object in the iteration and the values of which use data from the current.

```
$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
    baseLayers[idx] = new Array();
    baseLayers[idx][obj.name] = new L.TileLayer(obj.url, {maxZoom: 18, id: obj.key, attribution: mbAttr});
});
```

at the end, I want to get result an object like this

```
baseLayers = {
        'Map Box': new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 18, id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7', attribution: mbAttr}),
        'OSM': new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 18, attribution: mbAttr})
};
```

Comment: What is your current code producing?

Comment: 'Map Box' and 'OSM' is what I'm getting from `obj.name`

Comment: I just noticed, after `$.each` block when I tried to get length of `baseLayer[0]` it gives as `0` but, it has key `baseLayers[0]['Map Box']`

Comment: JSON is a string. There is no JSON in this post. After JSON has been deserialized into a data structure, your question is about working with those structures, not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var baseLayers = {}
$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
    baseLayers[obj.name] = new L.TileLayer(obj.url, {maxZoom: 18, id: obj.key, attribution: mbAttr});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what data looks like I believe you want:

```
var baseLayers = {};
$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {       
    baseLayers[obj.name] = new L.TileLayer(obj.url, {maxZoom: 18, id: obj.key, attribution: mbAttr});
});
```

You are trying to add an extra level which is not shown in your expected output

Comment: yes, there was an extra level just removed and it works. thanks!